# CodeIgniter error when migrating to new server

Tags: codeigniter

I a receiving a 404 error on a CodeIgniter site after migrating to a new webserver.

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntBtr.jpg)

New server is running PHP 5.4.45; old server was runnng 5.4.38. I've switched to newer versions of PHP on the new server, but the 404 error still appears. I tested that Mod_Rewrite in the .htaccess files was working (using https://docs.bolt.cm/3.0/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works) and it appears to be working.

I still have my old webserver online, and the site still works properly on the old server. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I tried uploading the site to a new GoDaddy account, and it worked fine there. But I still can't determine why it's not working on the other webserver.

Comment: Check `autoload.php` for did you load all the helpers. Check `base_url`. Use proper `htaccess` check throw stack. you can find.

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter is this?

Comment: It is version 2.0.3